# Create a DockPanel control with secondary content

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, dockpanel

I would like to create a custom control that provides all the functionality of the *DockPanel*, but it also exposes a secondary *Overlay* that is "outside" of the *DockPanel*. There would be a dependency property that will control the visibility of the the overlay panel, such that when the property is set true/visible, the Panel will appear overlayed on top of everything within the DockPanel.

Ideally the consumer would be able to drop the control into the same situation as a normal DockPanel, and with no other changes it would behave just like the normal DockPanel:

```
<DockPanelWithOverlay LastChildFill="True" >
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom".../>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top".../>          
    <Grid>
        <Grid controls.../>
    </Grid>
</DockPanelWithOverlay>
```

However, there would be available the secondary area into which they could place the additional content and invoke when required.

```
<DockPanelWithOverlay LastChildFill="True" >
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom".../>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top".../>   
    <Grid>
        <Grid controls.../>
    </Grid>  
    <DockPanel.Overlay>
        <whatever controls for the overlay>
    </DockPanel.Overlay>     
</DockPanelWithOverlay>
```

But that wouldn't be valid since the Content is being set twice? So to cope, when using the overlay I guess I would have to explicitly state what goes where?:

```
<DockPanelWithOverlay LastChildFill="True" >
    <DockPanel.Children>
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom".../>
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top".../>   
        <Grid>
            <Grid controls.../>
        </Grid>    
    </DockPanel.Children> 
    <DockPanel.Overlay  Visibility="{Binding IsVisible}">
        <whatever controls for the overlay>
    </DockPanel.Overlay>  
</DockPanelWithOverlay>
```

I'm not entirely sure the best way to tackle this: whether to create a CustomControl, or a UserControl, inherit directly from the DockPanel and try to expose a separate ContentControl, or maybe inherit from Panel and delegate the MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride to the DockPanel.

How should I tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. I wrote a DockPanelWithOverlay component that does the work:

[image: DockPanel with semi transparent overlay]

I chose here the CustomControl because I wanted to have inheritance of Panel.
But Panel doesn't have a template it can change.
So I wrote a Custom Control inheriting of Control with a custom template
But a Usercontrol would perfectly work I think (I didn't try to be honest)

**Edit** UserControl is not so good, because it inherits of ContentControl.
So it can only have one children.
The goal of the DockPanelWithOverlay is to have many children.
So I think UserControl is not the best inheritance, as often.
UserControl is better when you want to provide some content in xaml, mostly static, not customizable by user of control.

**End of edit**

To organize content inside the tempalte, I used a Grid.
Order of the two components matters.
It is the drawing order.

Grid allows to put two components at the same place :
Inside there'll be the Overlay control, and a underlying DockPanel.

DockPanelWithOverlay
..|
..|-ControlTemplate
......|
......|-Grid
..........|
..........|--DockPanel
..........|--OverlayControl

Having a template is easier to make some binding from the DockPanelWithOverlay to the template's controls properties. 
(To generate a CustomControl, create a WPFCustom Control Library Project)

Excerpt of themes\generic.xaml in library :

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:DockPanelWithOverlay}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:DockPanelWithOverlay}">
                <!-- the grid allows to put two components at the same place -->
                <Grid >
                    <DockPanel x:Name="dockPanel" />
                    <ContentControl x:Name="overlayControl" Visibility="{TemplateBinding OverlayVisibility}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Inheriting of control allows to use the template to create the small UIElements hierarchy.

Some dependency properties must be added for allowing binding :

1. Overlay for providing some UIElements, or a string for overlay content
2. OverlayVisibility for hiding/showing the overlay

Here is the code for the DockPanelWithOverlay :
(Note the OnApplytemplate called just after the templates componenets are called)

```
 // Children is the property that will be valued with the content inside the tag of the control 
[ContentProperty("Children")]
public class DockPanelWithOverlay : Control
{
    static DockPanelWithOverlay()
    {
        // Associate the control with its template in themes/generic.xaml
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DockPanelWithOverlay), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(DockPanelWithOverlay)));
    }
    public DockPanelWithOverlay()
    {
        Children = new UIElementCollection(this, this);
    }
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        // once the template is instanciated, the dockPanel and overlayCOntrol can be found from the template
        // and the children of DockPanelWithOverlay can be put in the DockPanel
        var dockPanel = this.GetTemplateChild("dockPanel") as DockPanel;
        if (dockPanel != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < Children.Count; )
            {
                UIElement elt = Children[0];
                Children.RemoveAt(0);
                dockPanel.Children.Add(elt);
            }
    }   
    // Here is the property to show or not the overlay
    public Visibility OverlayVisibility
    {
        get { return (Visibility)GetValue(OverlayVisibilityProperty); }
        set { SetValue(OverlayVisibilityProperty, value); }
    }
    // Here is the overlay. Tipically it could be a Texblock, 
    // or like in our example a Grid holding a TextBlock so that we could put a semi transparent backround
    public Object Overlay
    {
        get { return (Object)GetValue(OverlayProperty); }
        set { SetValue(OverlayProperty, value); }
    }
    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for OverlayProperty. 
    // This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty OverlayProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Overlay", typeof(Object), typeof(DockPanelWithOverlay), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty OverlayVisibilityProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("OverlayVisibility", typeof(Visibility), typeof(DockPanelWithOverlay), new PropertyMetadata(Visibility.Visible));
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public UIElementCollection Children
    {
        get { return (UIElementCollection)GetValue(ChildrenProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ChildrenProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ChildrenProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Children", typeof(UIElementCollection), typeof(DockPanelWithOverlay), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

Using the DockPanelWithOverlay :

```
<lib:DockPanelWithOverlay x:Name="dockPanelWithOverlay1" 
                                OverlayVisibility="Visible"              
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Button Content="Top" Height="50" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="Red"/>
    <Button Content="Bottom" Height="50" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Background="Yellow"/>
    <Button Content="Left" Width="50" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Background="Pink"/>
    <Button Content="Right" Width="50" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Background="Bisque"/>
    <Button Content="Center" Background="Azure"/>
    <lib:DockPanelWithOverlay.Overlay>
        <Grid Background="#80404080">
            <TextBlock Text="Overlay" FontSize="80" Foreground="#FF444444" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="-15"/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </lib:DockPanelWithOverlay.Overlay>
</lib:DockPanelWithOverlay>
```

The overlay can easily be switched on or off binding from a CheckBox.IsChecked property for instance.

Here is the full working code : http://1drv.ms/1NfCl9z

I think it 's really the answer to your question. Regards

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the sort of thing I was looking for.

Comment: I like this and am going to study it carefully. Thank you, Emmanuel.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest we should try to clarify how you see this working. My guess is that the secondary panel will be a `DockPanel` too, and will completely cover the main panel. I.e., you see either the one or the other, but never both. How do you envisage switching between the two? A `ToggleButton` perhaps? Or only under control of, say, some `Trigger`?

My first thought as to implementation is that you seem to like how `DockPanel`? lays things out, so why touch the layout methods? One way might be to have only one dockpanel, but two collections of children, which you set according to which you want to show. Or the secondary panel in a `Popup?

Do you want to be able to write something like this:

```
<DockPanelWithAlternative
    AlternativeVisibility="{Binding somethingHere}" >
    <TextBlock Dock.Top ... />
    <TextBlock Dock.Alternative.Top ... />

</DockPanelWithAlternative>
```

What I am thinking of is something like:

```
<UserControl>
   <Grid>
      <DockPanel x:Name="MainPanel" ZIndex="0"/>
      <DockPanel x:Name="AlternativePanel" Visbility=... ZIndex="1"/>
   </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @PScr. I was anticipating the secondary Panel to potentially host anything, the consumer could then insert a DockPanel if required.  It would typically be used to convey a message to the user, but focussed very much on that control, rather than using a generic application dialog. It might transition in, or have some subtle transparency to allow some of the main DockPanel to show through.

Comment: Yes, I see. Perhaps we should think in terms of a `UserControl` with a `DockPanel` and a `ContentControl`that sits on top. Then you can have a `DataTemplate` for the `ContentControl` which ther user could set: <DockPanelWithX XTempleate=... XContent=... XVisibility=... />

Comment: I have just been reading this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/820324/Implementing-Dialog-Boxes-in-MVVM. Perhaps there are some ideas you could adapt.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @Pscr, I've updated the question to include a little more detail.  I'm not trying to create a popup dialog, I'm more trying to understand the best or efficient way forward to create/extend a custom control. Thanks